# Browning bones in a skillet

Tags: oven, stock, bones, skillet

I want to try out some recipes that require a bone stock. Ideally a bone stock should be made with bones that have been roasted for 45 minutes, I  just moved and do not posses a oven. Is it possible to get the same roasted bone flavour with just a skillet or any other type of pan? If not, are there any alternatives for getting a proper bone stock?

Comment: If your skillet is oven safe to the temperature you want to roast at, will work fine. If not oven safe, not so fine.

Comment: So high heat, cover it with a lid and wait 45 minutes?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depending on what kind of stock pot or soup pot you intend to use, you can just brown the bones right in the bottom of the pot. I don't think my mom ever put bones in the oven to make soup.

Put a little oil in the bottom of the pot and brown the bones like you would sautee meat over medium high heat. When you've got the desired browning done, just pour in the water you will use to make the stock and boil the bones in the water like you would normally do.

Comment: Thank you, Todd! I will give it a try and see how it goes.